# Drawing multiple charts in a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

Partial View "PiePartial.cshtml":

```
@model IEnumerable<QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartValue>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var legend;

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        // PIE CHART
        chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
        chart.dataProvider = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        chart.titleField = "name";
        chart.valueField = "value";
        chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
        chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
        chart.outlineThickness = 2;

        // WRITE
        chart.write("piediv");
    });
</script>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartDraw

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/amcharts/pie.js"></script>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("PiePartial", Model.ProjectCount);
    Html.RenderPartial("PiePartial", Model.IsFailed);
}

<div id="piediv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Calling with `<div id="piediv">` just only show 1 chart of Model IsFailed, I think they have the same `id="piediv"` is the cause of it.

I want to show 2 pie charts with Model *ProjectCount* and *IsFailed* inside Index.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually change your code and move holder container directly in `PartialView`:

Partial View "PieChart.cshtml":

```
@model Tuple<string, IEnumerable<QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartValue>>
@{
  var controlId = Model.First;
}
<div id="@controlId" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var legend;

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        // PIE CHART
        chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
        chart.dataProvider = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Second));
        chart.titleField = "name";
        chart.valueField = "value";
        chart.outlineColor = "#FFFFFF";
        chart.outlineAlpha = 0.8;
        chart.outlineThickness = 2;

        // WRITE
        chart.write("@controlId");
    });
</script>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartDraw

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

    var ProjectCountData = new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartValue>>("ProjectCount", Model.ProjectCount);

    var IsFailedData = new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<QLCLDA.Models.Chart.ChartValue>>("ProjectCount",IsFailed);
}

<script src="~/Scripts/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/amcharts/pie.js"></script>

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("PiePartial", ProjectCountData);
    Html.RenderPartial("PiePartial", IsFailedData);
}
```

In that case you will have separated logic of creation charts from actual application logic and also you will be able to add as many charts as you want.

Comment: Thank for your help, I solved this problem!

I wrote wrong Partial View's name, correct name is "PiePartial.cshtml", but doesn't matter, I created a variable `controlId` like you and passed a random string :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you've solved your problem!
But actually it will be better to send not random controlId, but some correct value.